# Getting a jQuery toggle to work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to make a menu on the side of JavaScript. I wanted to handle this problem with jQuery toggle, but it did not happen. Is it because the position is relative?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hamburger Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }



        ul{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;  
        }

        ul li{
            display: block;
        }

        ul li a{
            display: block;
            padding: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }

        hr{
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
        }
        div{
            height: 400px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: red;  
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            right: 226px;
        }
        i{
            margin-left: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 24px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 201px;
            background-color: white;
            color: red;
            right: 46px;
            transition: all 1s ease ease-in-out;
        }

        ul li a:hover{
            background-color: rgb(0,108,250);
        }
        i:hover{
            color: rgb(0, 108, 250);
        }


    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("i").click(function(){
                $("#div1").toggle(500)
            })
        })

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
<div id="div1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="ana">Ana Sayfa</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id="hak">Hakkimizda</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id="ile">Iletisim</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id="rek">Reklam</a></li>

        <li><a href="#" id="more">Daha Fazla</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a few things going on here. First, you're toggling the entire menu to `display: none`, which removes it from the flow of the website. Then you have `bottom:201px` on your icon. So what's happening is that when the menu gets toggled out of the flow, the icon is pushed 201px off the visible page.

Remove position relative from everything, remove your right and bottom attributes as well as the margin-left on the icon. You'll see that it works. Then just position the icon at the top and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has to do with `position: relative`. I will explain what is going on:

Your `body` starts at the top of the viewport and is just as high as the highest of its children pushes it to be, so it stretches downwards to fits its children, but not more. Before toggling, `#div1` is the highest child. After toggling, `#div1` is hidden, so only the `<i></i>` remains, and the `body` will have a very low height.

Now when an element has `position: relative`, one thing that happens is that you can use `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` on it to move it *relative* to where it normally would be. Your `<i></i>` does have `position: relative`, and it also has `bottom: 201px`, so it gets moved up 201px. Normally, it would be at the top of the viewport, inside the `body`. When being moved up that far, it ends up outside of the viewport, so you can't see it anymore.

You can see all this visually for yourself using your Browser's developer tools, for example [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) for Firefox or Chrome's [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

Answer (score 0):

I've changed a bit in your css, but mainly I've moved the `i` after the `div`. Check it out and see if this is what you need.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("i").click(function() {
    $("#div1").toggle(500)
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

hr {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}

div {
  height: 400px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

i {
  top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left:5px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  transition: all 1s ease ease-in-out;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 108, 250);
}

i:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 108, 250);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




<div id="div1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="ana">Ana Sayfa</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" id="hak">Hakkimizda</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" id="ile">Iletisim</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" id="rek">Reklam</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" id="more">Daha Fazla</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your snippet with some changes:

- removed `position:relative` from CSS, the positioning is now flex-based (with margin)
- tweaked transition a bit and added some styles to make button movement smoother (check out a fix for `transition` property and `--menu_off` modifier class)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".js-menu-toggle-button").click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-container__toggle-button--menu_off');
                $(".js-menu-bar").toggle(500);
            })
        })
```

```css
*{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }



        ul{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;  
        }

        ul li{
            display: block;
        }

        ul li a{
            display: block;
            padding: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
            border-bottom: 1px solid white;
        }

        hr{
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
        }

        ul li a:hover{
            background-color: rgb(0,108,250);
        }
        i:hover{
            color: rgb(0, 108, 250);
        }

        .menu-container {
          display: flex;
        }

        .menu-container__menu-bar {
            height: 400px;
            width: 150px;
            background-color: red;  
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .menu-container__toggle-button {
            margin-left: 2rem;
            font-size: 24px;
            background-color: white;
            color: red;
            transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        }

        .menu-container__toggle-button--menu_off {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hamburger Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu-container__menu-bar js-menu-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="ana">Ana Sayfa</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" id="hak">Hakkimizda</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" id="ile">Iletisim</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" id="rek">Reklam</a></li>

            <li><a href="#" id="more">Daha Fazla</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <i class="fas fa-bars menu-container__toggle-button js-menu-toggle-button"></i>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```